# CSS Style for my Bootstrap are being overridden by User Agent Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, user-agent

I'm using twitter bootstrap for making a table layout. But, my custom styles are being overridden by something called as the User Agent Style sheet. I don't know what it it is. But it's causing me a lot of problems

Comment: I tried the doctype hack. That too did not work

Comment: Could you post a sample of the HTML you're using? Perhaps the CSS file is not being referenced correctly.